# How to get control in the application when SNMPV3 authentication fails using SNMP4J

Tags: snmp, snmp4j

I have a SNMP Agent developed with SNMP4J stack.

I have a security requirement where I need to monitor a manager if the v3 authentication fails.

Is only option is to change stack and add a callback mechanism when the authentication fails ?

I basically need to get the IP of the agent , Sniffing the packet is not an option for me.

How do I get the control in my application when the authentication fails. Are there any callback or some other way I can achieve.

I have posted this question in SNMP4J group , But I am unable to get a response.

Can someone give me a pointer about it ?

Comment: Yes, what your agent should send the Authentication Failure trap in this instance. How to do it in snmp4j, I'm not sure.

Comment: Questions seems like a broad.............. please explain with specific example